# How to install a directory tree of data with automake

Tags: automake

How can I install a directory tree of HTML files, stylesheets and images with automake without having to create Makefiles in each subdirectory?

Using the following in the toplevel directory

```
htmldir = $(docdir)/foo/html
html_DATA = \
        stylesheets/foo.css \
        images/foo.jpg \
        index.html \
        about/index.html \
        faq/index.html
EXTRA_DIST = $(html_DATA)
```

fails because the subdirectories are not created before `install` is called.

Answer (score 12):

You could write

```
foohtmldir = $(htmldir)/foo/html
nobase_dist_foohtml_DATA = \
    stylesheets/foo.css \
    images/foo.jpg \
    index.html \
    about/index.html \
    faq/index.html
```

`htmldir` is a variable the user is entitled to modify using `configure --htmldir=...` so I suggest using another one if you want to write to some subdirectory of it.  The `nobase_` prefix will tell Automake not to strip leading directories during installation, and the `dist_` prefix requires the files to be distributed.