# how to distribute all files in a data directory with automake

Tags: autoconf, automake

I have some data files used in my package.  They are 74 files in a directory.  According to [automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Data.html#Data) section *9.3 Architecture-independent data files* I can list them individually

```
dist_pkgdata_DATA = mydir/file1 mydir/file2 ..... mydir/file74
```

That's too much typing. Any one can suggest a good solution?
There is a [slightly different solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636158/how-to-install-a-directory-tree-of-data-with-automake) for such a problem, but it is essentially the same mechanism (listing all files manually). Since programmers are lazy, we don't want to type them. Furthermore, each time you need to add new files or remove old file, you have to update the Makefile.am.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to list files at all [the compressed file approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6411823/425738) with it's install/uninstall hooks look like a reasonable approach for a lot of files, especially if they are essentially "write only".

If you want to have those files normally inspectable you'll have to do something like:

```
MYDIR = mydir
EXTRA_DIST = $(MYDIR)

install-data-local:
        test -z $(pkgdatadir) || $(MKDIR_P) $(pkgdatadir)
        find "$(MYDIR)" -type f -exec $(INSTALL_DATA) {} $(pkgdatadir) \;
```

The "too much typing" part is due to the `dist_` prefix -- `automake` is being told to package up those files for the distribution tarball.  `EXTRA_DIST` on the other hand will include the entire contents of a directory into the tarball, but you have to specify what to do with those files later.  And it really doesn't check, either.   If `mydir` has 2 files or 74 files, it's all the same to `automake`.

Another way to solve it is to have another program in [`bootstrap.sh`](https://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_43.html#Bootstrapping) (before `autoreconf` is invoked) make a makefile fragment defining `dist_pkgdata_DATA` which is then `included` in `Makefile.am`.  This still doesn't fix the correct number of files problem either.